# Let $l=+\infty$ then $ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=l $ if and only if $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\exists n>N$ such that $x_n>\lambda$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $l=+\infty$ then $ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=l $ if and only if $\forall N\in\mathbb{N}\exists n>N$ such that $x_n>\lambda$

**My attempt**
Let $\lambda>0$.

By hypothesis we know $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=l$ then
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n={\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}}_{k\geq n}x_k=l$$

Then exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ then $\text{sup}_{k\geq n}x_k>\lambda$ then

$x_n>\lambda$ for each $n>N$

is good this?

for the other implication i'm stuck. can someone help me?

Comment: What is $\lambda$?

Comment: a real number @GEdgar

Comment: Should there be a quantifier for $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last step you should say there exists $k \geq n$ such that $x_k >\lambda$. It is wrong to say $x_n >\lambda$ for all $n >N$.

Converse: if the condition holds then $\sup \{x_k: k>N\} >\lambda$ so $\lim \sup x_n \geq \lambda$. Since $\lambda$ is arbitrary it follows that $\lim \sup x_n=\infty$.